# HTML Storing canvas data, canvas drawing disappear on manual re-size [Tiff.js]

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, angularjs-directive

As i already faced many unanswered question, i'm wonder if there are any ways...

I'm using Tiff.js library to provide in browser tiff viewer, but the issue is that this library decide on how the tiff should be draws, and any change since then on the canvas make the drawing to disappear.

i used this library: http://htmlcheats.com/html/resize-the-html5-canvas-dyamically/

only this part:

```
        function resizeCanvas() {
            htmlCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            htmlCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            redraw();
        }
```

to re-size my canvas...:

```
app.directive('tiffViewer', [
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

                function resizeCanvas(htmlCanvas) {
                    htmlCanvas.width = elem.innerWidth();
                    htmlCanvas.height = elem.innerHeight();
                }
                
                reload();

                function reload() {
                    var src = attrs.src;
                    src += "?ver=" + Date.now();
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
                    xhr.open('GET', src);
                    xhr.onload = function (e) {
                        Tiff.initialize({ TOTAL_MEMORY: 134217728 });//Need More Memory Once Switching To Big Files
                        var tiff = new Tiff({ buffer: xhr.response});
                        var canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
                        resizeCanvas(canvas);
                        //document.body.append(canvas);
                        elem.empty();
                        elem.append(canvas);
                        tiff.close();
                    };
                    xhr.send();
                }; //On Initialize

                attrs.$observe('src', function () {
                    reload();
                }); //On Data Change

                //On Refresh Broadcast
                var refreshMessage = attrs.dataRefreshMessage || attrs.refreshMessage;
                if (refreshMessage) {
                    scope.$on(refreshMessage, function (event, args) {
                        reload();
                    });
                }

            }
        }
    }
]);
```

As i said after re-sizing the content will disappear. or if i don't do this, the content it self take size as big as the real image size is, and destroy my layout.

even [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179274/html-canvas-drawing-disappear-on-resizing) doesn't seem to be the right way to help me.

Thank you,

Hassan F.

Comment: You should save your unscaled canvas in some variable, without ever changing its size, or in an `<img>` tag with its src set to the `canvas.toDataURL()` return. Then, you will only resize an other canvas and call the `ctx.drawImage(savedCanvas, 0,0, newWidth, newWidth)`

Comment: the first, the image i mean....> so i create my canvas, but do not load it over the page, then, i create image, then get img id, and retreive the element, set it's source to canvas.toDataURL, and in the end i do work with the image tag?

Comment: no, `tiff.toCanvas();` seems to return a canvas element right ? Then, keep this original canvas in memory (in a global variable), create an other canvas, resize this new canvas, `newCtx.drawImage()` the saved canvas, append the new canvas. At each resize, redraw the savedCanvas after resizing.

Comment: thanks so much, i'll try it right away

Comment: worked fine... you can put your answer