# Huge background-image in Firefox disappear at least after resize

Tags: html, css, firefox, resize, background-image

I want to load a huge jpg with 48000x990px as background-image.

HTML:

```
<div id="car-canvas-wrapper">
  <div id="car-canvas" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/48000x320');"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#car-canvas-wrapper {
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
}

#car-canvas {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 51.5625%;
}
```

You will find a example in CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ypyMpZ

In Chrome, Edge, Internet Explorer and Safari everything works great. But in Firefox there are some heavy problems. Sometimes the image loads when i clean the cache. If its loads and i resize the window, the image disappear. In the inspector i see, after resize, that the background-image got 0x0px.

Obviously the picture is too big. Question: Why can all browsers except Firefox display the image?

**Edit:** I removed the huge image from my webserver and insert a placeholder image (48000x320px). Keep that in mind if you have a similar problem and read this thread.

Comment: The question is actually interesting, is it possible because it is a canvas?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179274/html-canvas-drawing-disappear-on-resizing

Comment: it is no canvas

Comment: there is no canvas, and im not seeing the image on any browser...

Comment: what version of Firefox do you have? if i create a code snippet from your code i see it in all browsers.

Comment: maybe try adding this css to `#car-canvas-wrapper { display: block;}` could fix the problem.

Comment: Firefox Version 57.0.1 (64-Bit) on Mac Sierra 10.12.6
and 57.0.2 (64-bit) on Windows 10

Comment: I can see the image on firefox 58.0b10 (64-bit)

Comment: @Ylama with display:block it is working! But why?
And there is a new problem but only with Windows!: The image is also animated (with background-position-x) there is a swipe from 0% to -2400%. When the animation is done the image is very blurred, but should be sharp.

Comment: Firefox is buggy with images so im not 100% sure i would be telling bit of an lie if i said anything more.. but i have also ran into this problem and i remember firefox likes `block` on images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox fix on images could be more than just this simple solution but i have found this as a working solution on previous project.

Just add the following `css`:

```
#car-canvas-wrapper { display: block;}
```

Should do the trick.