# Change Canvas Size Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to draw something on a canvas and resize it to its content, while a surrounding div is responsible for scrolling the canvas content.

What I have so far. The very basic HTML code looks like this:

```js
function init() {
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
 var max = 5;
 var rectWidth = 30;
 var rectHeight = 30;
  
 for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  ctx.fillRect(i * rectWidth, i * rectHeight, rectWidth, rectHeight);
 } 
 ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 overflow: scroll;
}
#canvas {}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="init();">
 <div id="wrapper"> 
  <canvas id="canvas" />
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What happens (at least in FireFox and Chrome) is that the canvas is about 100x100 pixels big and you can scroll a bit (because the scroll bars sizes are subtracted from the 100px).

What I want to have is that all 5 squares are visible when scrolling.

What I tried:

```css
#canvas {
    /* these screw up the scaling of the canvas, i.e. the squares become rectangles  */
    height: 100%; width: 100%
    /* or */
    height: 150px; width: 150px;
}
```

```js
function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    // [snip]

    // this makes the canvas invisible
    canvas.width = max * rectWidth;
    canvas.height = max * rectHeight;
}
```

```xml
<!-- works, but is not dynamic -->
<canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150" />
```

I tried combining these approaches, but neither really satisfied my needs.

How do I change the canvas's size dynamically?

Comment: Put all this in a snippet please?

Comment: In some browsers you must set both the canvas element's attribute values for width and height to the same value as the width and height properties. Try setting both - see what happens.

Comment: @RandyCasburn A snippet like this? And it doesn't matter what I do the moment I add `canvas.width = 150;` in JS the canvas vanishes. And JS is the only place where setting the size makes sense, because since it's dynamic there is no way to set it in CSS or HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamically setting the canvas size is discussed here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#Sizing_the_canvas_using_CSS_versus_HTML

> The displayed size of the canvas can be changed using CSS, but if you
>   do this the image is scaled during rendering to fit the styled size,
>   which can make the final graphics rendering end up being distorted.
>
> It is better to specify your canvas dimensions by setting the width
>   and height attributes directly on the  elements, either
>   directly in the HTML or by using JavaScript.

You'll see in the solution I set the size *prior* to drawing on the canvas. If the canvas is sized after the shapes are drawn they are lost. The reason is because the pixel dimensions of the canvas have changed and the context is lost (the canvas has been reset). You can also see this on this SO post: [HTML canvas - drawing disappear on resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179274/html-canvas-drawing-disappear-on-resizing)

```js
function init() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var wrapper = canvas.parentNode;
  canvas.setAttribute("width", window.getComputedStyle(wrapper).width);
  canvas.setAttribute("height", window.getComputedStyle(wrapper).height);

  var max = 5;
  var rectWidth = 30;
  var rectHeight = 30;
  canvas.setAttribute("width", (max) * rectWidth + "px");
  canvas.setAttribute("height", (max) * rectHeight + "px");

  for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    ctx.fillRect(i * rectWidth, i * rectHeight, rectWidth, rectHeight);
  }
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body onload="init();">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <canvas id="canvas" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```