# Keep canvas image after resizing

Tags: javascript, canvas

I need to resize a canvas, and I do it like this:

```
canvas.height = newHeight;
canvas.width = newWidth;
```

But after I do so, the image disappears. How do I make it to rescale according to the new canvas size?

Comment: The image will need to be redrawn after resizing.

Comment: See this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179274/html-canvas-drawing-disappear-on-resizing